# Javafx: How to get ID of clicked Text element

Tags: java, javafx

I have an Icon (based on Text) element and I can't get its ID when the element is clicked.

When I print mouseEvent.getSource() it is returning below text and there is an id:

```
Text[id=bathroom, text="", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL, font=Font[name=FontAwesome Regular, family=FontAwesome, style=Regular, size=60.0], fontSmoothingType=GRAY, fill=0x000000ff]
```

Id can be parsed from the text. But, I'm looking for proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add following code to your MouseClickedEvent.

```
Text txt=(Text) mouseEvent.getSource();
System.out.println(txt.getId());
```

Comment: @Sarvar Nishonboyev Please accept the answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something similar to this:

```
text.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event)
    {
        Text text1 = (Text) event.getSource();
        System.out.println(text1.getId());
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a password field, any FX Component that you can give an ID should work.

Comment: no, Text is not Control type. I tried already, it gives an error

Comment: Could you post your `MouseEvent` code in your question then?